# How to set permissions on virtual network directory when application pool uses LOCALSYSTEM?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a Windows 10 web server development machine (let's call it: "DEVELOPMENTMACHINE") where the application pool uses LOCALSYSTEM. Without using LOCALSYSTEM, the Windows text-to-speech wouldn't work on some voices.

Now I'm trying to set up a virtual directory pointing to a directory on another machine that is shared, via a reference like "\OTHERMACHINE\ShareName". This directory, which also is a web server directory on that machine, has the user names and permissions for "IUSR" and "IIS_IUSRS(OTHERMACHINE\IIS_IUSRS)" set up, as well as being readable and writable as a normal shared directory. However, when I run the development website on DEVELOPMENTMACHINE, it can't access the "\OTHERMACHINE\ShareName" directory.  I need the DEVELOPMENTMACHINE web server code (ASP.NET) to be able to read and write to that share, just like it does to its local directory. What do I need to set up to make this work?

Comment: This question is more suitable to be asked at https://serverfault.com that is another Stack Exchange web site like Stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when you tried to access?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the serverfault suggestion.  I got this response: https://serverfault.com/questions/1064676/how-to-set-permissions-on-virtual-network-directory-when-application-pool-uses-l

I should be offloading the text-to-speech to a Windows service, and then I can use a regular app pool, which I'm guessing should let me set up the permissions better.